# Count number of records between hour spans in TSQL

Tags: t-sql, hour

I'm trying to count the number of transactions made between 8AM-8PM (for example in - May 2o 2013) in comparison to 8PM-8AM (of the following day)

The field that has those times is called - `CREATED_DT`

The field for the items being sold is called - `ITEM_ID`

Can anyone please help? Couldn't find it on the forum.

Thanks,
Or.

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(ITEM_ID) from your_table
where CREATED_DT between '2013-05-20 08:00:00' and '2013-05-20 20:00:00'
```

Comment: I get the following error - SELECT Failed.  [3535] A character string failed conversion to a numeric value. Could it be that the CREATED_DT is a string and not numeric in the system?

Comment: @user3655929: You tell me. It is your table. But it is probably so. In that case you should show some example data. Then we can convert that to a `datetime`

Answer (score 0):

Something, like this:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(1)

FROM 
    dbo.YOUR_TABLE

WHERE
    CAST(CREATED_DT AS DATE) = '03.20.2013'
    AND
    CAST(CREATED_DT AS TIME(0)) BETWEEN '08:00:00' AND '20:00:00'
```

MSDN: [TSQL time](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677243%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Comment: I get the following error - SELECT Failed. [3535] A character string failed conversion to a numeric value. Could it be that the CREATED_DT is a string and not numeric in the system?

Comment: Maybe, `CREATED_DT` must be `DATETIME` type. If not - u can convert it: `CONVERT(DATETIME, CREATED_DT, 101)`

Answer (score 0):

Since you are looking for relative count

```
select day2-day1 from
(
    select 
        sum(case when created_dt = '2013-05-20' then 1 else 0 end) as day1
        , sum(case when created_dt = '2013-05-21' then 1 else 0 end) as day2 
    from your_table
    where CREATED_DT between '2013-05-20 08:00:00' and '2013-05-20 20:00:00' 
    or CREATED_DT between '2013-05-21 08:00:00' and '2013-05-21 20:00:00'
)t
```

Answer (score 0):

This gives in btw 8am and 8pm

```
select count(ITEM_ID) from your_table
    where CREATED_DT between 
    CONVERT(varchar(15),CAST('2013-05-20 08:00:00' AS TIME),100) and 
CONVERT(varchar(15),CAST('2013-05-20 20:00:00' AS TIME),100)
```

Comment: I get an the following error - SELECT Failed.  [3706] Syntax error: expected something between ',' and the 'CAST' keyword.

Comment: I can't, I'm on Teradate on a large organization, can't duplicate the scheme.